# Transpose a Python list of lists

Tags: python

I want to switch rows and columns so:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

would turn into:

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

I know my list has a fixed 4rows*4columns. After I switch, I will have a function that manipulates it then switches is back.

I've tried using the zip function but it doesn't seem to work how I want it. Any built in functions or other ways to do this?

Comment: Have a loc at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the common `zip` idiom:

```
>>> zip(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```